# Determine S3 Bucket Region

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS Ruby SDK v2 to access various buckets across a couple of regions. Is it possible to determine the region of (at runtime) of each bucket before I access it, so I can avoid the error below, which I get if I configure the AWS S3 client with the wrong region?

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

I know I can shell out and use the command below and parse the response, but ideally, I want to stay within the Ruby SDK.

> aws s3api get-bucket-location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any official document for this, but from the [aws-sdk spec](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/4ee9c952b21c4d011b6763c227d3471cbcd8f3dd/aws-sdk-core/features/s3/step_definitions.rb#L56) you should be able to use following code to get the region

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new()
resp = client.get_bucket_location(bucket: bucket_name)
s3_region = resp.data.location_constraint
```

This one is calling the same API as `aws s3api get-bucket-location`

Comment: Thanks! I searched around for that method you mentioned, and it was actually in the API docs this whole time! I don't know how I missed it...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_bucket_location-instance_method

Comment: For aws-sdk (2.6.5), it is:

client.get_bucket_location(bucket: bucket_name).location_constraint

Comment: Don't you already have to know the region in order to sign the get_bucket_location request? If the bucket isn't in the same region as the client, you'll just get the same error as the questioner

Comment: @SamLiddicott `get_bucket_location` api will work in any region, else the api will be useless. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-location.html

Comment: @number5 if I issue a raw get_bucket_location request over https, to the wrong region (and correctly signed for the wrong region) I get the AuthorizationHeaderMalformed error, the connection is closed. Fortunately the error gives the right region in the <Region> tag.

If this works for ruby, it must be parsing the error.

Comment: @SamLiddicott OP and my answer both talking about AWS Ruby SDK, not the *HTTP RAW API*

Answer (score 1):

For aws-sdk (2.6.5), it is:

`client.get_bucket_location(bucket: bucket_name).location_constraint`

But then, now, how we get a list of buckets that belong to a specific region?